# Import extension for category

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, import, csv, data

Is there an extension which allows me to import the meta description for categories? Using version 1.9 community edition.

Answer (score 0):

I think danslo/ApiImport https://github.com/danslo/ApiImport may be suitable.

EDIT

With this extension you can import (not only) category entities.

> By default it will assume you are importing products. If you want to
>   import a different kind of entity, use the return value of any of
>   these methods:
>
> Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product::getEntityTypeCode()
>   Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Customer::getEntityTypeCode()
>   **Danslo_ApiImport_Model_Import_Entity_Category::getEntityTypeCode()**

And you can of course modify the data, not only insert new entities:

> Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE - Simply replaces the
>   data in Magento with whatever you have in the entity array. Any data
>   you do not specify in your array will not be deleted!

You can use it writing simple php script, and running it via browser or in terminal (command-line):

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::init();

$api = Mage::getModel('api_import/import_api');
$api->importEntities($anArrayWithYourEntities, $entityType, $optionalImportBehavior);
```

Please note that the input data has to be an array of entities (categories), so you may need to prepare your data if you have it in csv or spreadsheet.
Take a look at example input array here https://github.com/danslo/ApiImport/wiki/Example-Import-Array

Comment: Please don't post single link answers. Explain in a few words what the extension does